# C# Windows Forms App - Panel AutoScroll Property Bug

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, autoscroll, scrollable

I discovered a problem on the Windows Forms Application Panel component.

Firstly, I place a Panel object inside an empty form and enlarge it to fill the form.

[image]

Then I activate the Right, Left, Top and Bottom Anchor options and the AutoScroll feature.

[image]

Then, by adding a Group Box to the Panel, I make its size larger than the panel and activate the Right, Left and Top Anchor options. (GroupBox Width: 424, Height: 277)

[image]

As can be seen, a VerticalScrollBar appeared on the Panel as the size of the Group Box increased in length and the AutoScroll feature was active. No problems so far. Now I close and reopen the Form Designer screen.

[image]

As you can see in the image, when the Designer screen is closed and opened, the new size of the GroupBox, which was Width: 424, Height: 277, changed to Width: 407, Height: 277. In other words, it has shrunk to 17px in width. The system does this automatically, not me, and I can't understand what caused the problem.

[image]

The same problem persists during runtime.

I tried various Custom Components to solve this problem. One of them was setting the Panel's VerticalScroll.Enabled property to true in its constructor method, but that method didn't work either.

I'm asking for help on the subject, thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It is a bug in the layout logic, triggered by the Right anchor.  At issue is that the panel initializes itself without a scrollbar at first.  Then it gets the groupbox, discovers it now needs a scrollbar.  Which takes space, leaving less room horizontally, and dutifully makes the groupbox smaller to honor the anchor.  Automatic layout has several bugs like this that got never fixed.  Simplest way to avoid the bug is to turn off the Right anchor, turning it back on in the constructor of the form.

Comment: You can set your GroupBox to `Dock = Top` instead and use the Panel's `Padding` to fine-tune the GroupBox position. Docking is *conservative*